# Prove that perpendiculars from D,E,F to BC,CA,AB are concurrent?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Question -

If ABC and DEF be any two triangles such that the perpendiculars from the points A,B,C to the sides EF,FD,DE respectively, are concurrent. Prove that the perpendiculars from D,E,F to BC,CA,AB respectively are also concurrent.

My attempt -

First of all I know this question has already been answered but there they used carnots theorem and some other things which I haven't learn yet...

I am not able to figure it out using ceva theorem...I draw two triangles forming STAR  ...but did not get anything worth..then I draw both triangle on same plane but then things become very confusing...

I want some hint or how to draw correctly this thing...
Thankyou

Answer (score 2):

Let $AA_1,$ $BB_1$, $CC_1,$  $DD_1$, $EE_1$ and $FF_1$ be our perpendiculars.

Thus, $$\measuredangle(AA_1,AC)=\measuredangle(EE_1,FE),$$
$$\measuredangle(AA_1,AB)=\measuredangle(FF_1,FE),$$
$$\measuredangle(FF_1,FD)=\measuredangle(BB_1,AB),$$
$$\measuredangle(BB_1,BC)=\measuredangle(DD_1,FD),$$
$$\measuredangle(DD_1,DE)=\measuredangle(CC_1,BC)$$ and
$$\measuredangle(CC_1,AC)=\measuredangle(EE_1,DE).$$
Thus, our statement follows from the Ceva's theorem in the trigonometric form.

Comment: I am referring to "ceva" theorem that uses  (relation with ratio of sides) to prove concurrency ! How this is related...?

Comment: @IMO 2021 GOLD See here https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Ceva%27s_Theorem the Ceva's theorem in the trigonometric form.

Comment: I think I am referring to wrong diagram that's why not understanding ...can yu pls give your diagram...

Comment: @IMO 2021 GOLD I don't know to draw in the net. Draw six points $A,F,B,D,C,E$ in this ordering  as vertexes of a hexagon. I am sure that you'll see it.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the answer to your question. This is the depicture of your problem description, which you had trouble in drawing. I hope this will help you to find an appropriate answer.

[image: Two Triangles]

Comment: By your picture we can see, why equalities, which I wrote are true. But I think, would be better if you'll draw the picture, which I said to draw. See please comments under my post Thank you!

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg When i drew the sketch, I used the letters mentioned by the OP in his question, because I was addressing one of his request. I have already seen your comment and known it would confirm your results if I used the letters you have proposed. I decided to let the OP to replace his notations with yours,